# C# Excel UDF range write back get an error, Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions

```
public string Name(string code)
    {
        MyExcelAppInstance.Volatile(true);

        MsExcel.Application oApp = new MsExcel.Application();
        oApp.Visible = true;
        oApp.UserControl = true;
        Object oBooks = oApp.Workbooks;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        oBooks.GetType().InvokeMember("Add", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oBooks, null, ci);

        oApp.Visible = true;
        oApp.UserControl = true;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo oldCI = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        oApp.Workbooks.Add();
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;

        MsExcel.Range rng = MyExcelAppInstance.get_Range("A1:D4", Type.Missing);
        //Get a 2D Array of values from the range in one shot: 
        object[,] myArray = (object[,])rng.get_Value(Type.Missing);

        // Process 'myArray' however you want here. 
        // Note that the Array returned from Excel is base 1, not base 0. 
        // To be safe, use GetLowerBound() and GetUpperBound: 
        for (int row = myArray.GetLowerBound(0); row <= myArray.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
        {
            for (int column = myArray.GetLowerBound(1); column <= myArray.GetUpperBound(1); column++)
            {
                if (myArray[row, column] is double)
                {
                    myArray[row, column] = (double)myArray[row, column] * 2;
                }
            }
        }

        // Pass back the results in one shot: 
        rng.set_Value(Type.Missing, myArray);  // where gets an error

        return code + code;
    }
```

I get an error, "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC".  I tried to set the locale, but didn't work. Without the set_value, it works fine.  Any idea why this doesn't work??

Comment: did you tried Value2? from where you are calling this function? is the sheet protected?

Comment: I tried Value2 as well, but didn't work and the sheet is not protected

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once and the error turned out to be caused by an invalid argument (I was passing the range string in an invalid format). Make sure that the range and all the array conents is valid when you call `set_Value`.